# combine three tables in join mysql

Tags: mysql

i'm trying to display the image, username and improtantly the replies that go along with the query. I used similar codes like the one below but for the reply column i keep getting a null or empty even if the info is full. Its for 3 tables one for header, images and reply. The header includes the userames and other info for user, the images the images and the reply the replies people make.

reply.mid is suppose to match images.mid so that the replies can be next to the images.

```
  SELECT images.id, images.who, header.username, images.message, images.name,     reply.reply
 FROM header, images
  LEFT JOIN reply ON reply.reply = reply.mid
OR reply.mid = images.mid
WHERE images.name IS NOT NULL = header.id
 AND images.who IS NOT NULL 
AND images.message IS NOT NULL 
 GROUP BY images.mid
```

Tale structure below. Sorry

```
  TABLE Header
  username
  id
  who
  where

 Table images
 message
 name
  mid  - id that auto increments when image is loaded
 id
 content

 Table reply
 mid  id that is taken from images mid to relate image to reply.
  reply
  id ----this is only for an id for a reply that is auto increment
```

UPDATE. Code above works.

Comment: You need to provide the schema of those 3 tables, otherwise we'll probably be unable to help you

Comment: you have problem with `images.name IS NOT NULL = header.id`

Comment: You're also combining old style joins and ANSI joins in one... don't.

Comment: thanks evyeryone. It seems my code above is fine. The problem was that i had previously loaded a reply without an MID which caused the query result to repeat that reply over and over confusing me. I had to break the code down to figure what the problem was. I'm I good or what.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments others made, you also have a GROUP BY which is used when doing aggregations (such as MIN(), MAX(), AVG(), etc) such as total sales per sales rep, per month, per year, etc.  By Grouping By the image ID, you would loose instances that a person may have had multiple replies.

Anyhow, a little cleanup on your query.  It is unclear how the header table links to the replies, and you had a LEFT-JOIN to replies, but then looking for IS NOT NULL of the image.  This would indicate an INNER join vs LEFT join.  I am shifting the query since you are looking for replies and those who come along for the ride for images, so be it.

```
SELECT  
      H.username, 
      I.id, 
      I.who, 
      I.message,  
      I.name, 
      R.reply
   FROM 
      replies R
         join header H
            on R.SomeKeyToLinkToHeader = H.SomeHeaderKeyLinkingToReplies
         LEFT join images I
            on R.ID = I.MID
            OR R.MID = I.MID
   WHERE
      I.MID IS NOT NULL
```

The test for IS NOT NULL only needs to really be on any one key column... if it's null, then the entire record is missing and would be null too. (ie: it couldn't find a match on EITHER of the replies "ID" or "MID" columns.

If you provided the table structures to better show the relationships between the tables, the above query would be obviously altered slightly.  You may have meant to use an ORDER BY instead of GROUP BY clause.

Comment: thanks for taking time to try to answer my question. Usually my question are complex and most of the time i only get some hints and not the answer a reason I didn't put the table structure at first. I will try your code out see if it works. i hate joining 3 tables.